# Wrong content inside an Oracle Date field

Tags: oracle, date, delphi, ado

Our Software collects measurements on an offline system. As part of the data collected the time of measurement is recorded. Storing measurements taken exactly at midnight and later reading them back with our software using Delphi 2006 via ADO and the OLEDB provider of Oracle 10 XE or Oracle 11 XE,  ADO throws an exception: "Fehler bei einem aus mehreren Schritten bestehenden Vorgang. Prüfen Sie die einzelnen Statuswerte." in English: "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value." 
A deeper analysis of the Message shows: Number of Errors = 1; Source = Microsoft Cursor Engine; NativeError = 0.

An analysis shows, that

> Select date_fld, DUMP(date_fld) from ...

gives p.Ex.:

> 21.01.16 00:00:00  | Typ=12 Len=7: 120,116,1,**20,25**,1,1

instead of:

> 21.01.16 00:00:00  | Typ=12 Len=7: 120,116,1,**21,1**,1,1

.

> Select TO_CHAR(date_fld, 'DD.MM.YY HH:MI:SS') from ...

gives

> 00.00.00  00:00:00

Data gets copied from the offline system to a server database using a public database link:

> Insert into Table_With_Date@Linked_DB (SELECT * from Table_With_Date
>   where ... )

This issue has been reported by some of our customers and is very hard to reproduce.

Is this a known bug of Oracle ?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Regards,
Lothar

Comment: Are you uploading the data as `UTC` but the session is set to the timezone `GMT-01:00`?

Comment: Do you know the exact text of the Ado exception?  If you do, add it to your q because readers shouldn't have to guess.  If you don't, install some exception logging in your app at the customers who have reported the problem, and get a record of it that way.

Comment: It may be an issue with the OleDB provider for Oracle... I've seen a lot of issues with it, e.g. about blobs. Try to update the provider with its latest version. Check the client library of all customers encountering issues. And/or try to use direct Oracle connection instead of ADO/OleDB.